# How to convert degrees, minutes, seconds and direction to longitude and latitude coordinates?

Tags: swift

I have a value like following value. I want to convert these value into longitude and latitude coordinates. If possible with math operations.

Input:

```
latitude: 40,58,36, N
longitude: 28,49, 16, E
```

Output:

```
latitude: 40.976667
longitude: 28.821111
```

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if there is a built-in function, but this will work:

```
func convert(degrees degrees: Double, minutes: Double, seconds: Double, direction: String) -> Double {
    let sign = (direction == "W" || direction == "S") ? -1.0 : 1.0
    return (degrees + (minutes + seconds/60.0)/60.0) * sign
}


let lattitude = convert(degrees: 40, minutes: 58, seconds: 36, direction: "N")  // 40.9766666666667
let longitude = convert(degrees: 28, minutes: 49, seconds: 16, direction: "W")  // -28.8211111111111
```

Answer (score 0):

you can extend your String class:
Swift3 example:

```
extension String {
    func convertCoordinatesToInteger() -> Double {
        let array = self.components(separatedBy: ",")
        let sign = (array[2] == "W" || array[2] == "S") ? -1.0 : 1.0
        let deg = Double(array[0])!
        let min = Double(array[1])!
        let sec = Double(array[2])!
        return (deg + (min + sec/60.0)/60.0) * sign
    }
```

Simply call this function on your Coordinates String

```
let myLatitude = "40,58,36,N".convertCoordinatesToDouble()
```